# PhpPresentation imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format - PHP7.2

Tags: php, phppresentation

I am trying to use PhpPresentation to read a `sample.pptx` file using the simple instructions for readers in their docs and I am getting:

`imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format`

I have checked that I have PHP7.2-gd installed and all of the other dependencies.

My Code:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use \PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\PhpPresentation;
use \PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\IOFactory;
use \PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Color;
use \PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Alignment;

$oReader = IOFactory::createReader('PowerPoint2007');
$data = $oReader->load(__DIR__ . '/sample.pptx');
var_dump($data);
```

Can anybody help me understand the issue?

Comment: It's part of the package ```vendor/phpoffice/phppresentation/src/PhpPresentation/Reader/PowerPoint2007.php```

Comment: Is the full stack trace there? can we see?

Comment: Probably you've got an unsupported image embedded in the presentation. This question is better suited for the author of the package.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After peeking into [the PHP source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/gd/gd.c#L2287), to have some insights about the "[imagecreatefromstring](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php)" function, I've discovered that it handles only the following image formats:

- JPEG
- PNG
- GIF
- WBM
- GD2
- BMP
- WEBP

PHP recognizes the format of the image contained in the argument of the "imagecreatefromstring" function by checking the image signature, as explained [here](https://oroboro.com/image-format-magic-bytes/).
When an unknown signature is detected, the warning "Data is not in a recognized format" is raised.
Therefore, the only plausible explanation for the error that you are experiencing is that **your PPTX file contains an image that is not in one of the above formats**.
You can view the format of the images inside your PPTX file by changing its extension from ".pptx" to ".zip" and then opening it.
You should see something like this:

```
Archive:  sample.pptx
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
     5207  1980-01-01 00:00   [Content_Types].xml
      ...
     6979  1980-01-01 00:00   ppt/media/image1.jpeg
     6528  1980-01-01 00:00   ppt/media/image2.jpeg
   178037  1980-01-01 00:00   ppt/media/image3.jpeg
   229685  1980-01-01 00:00   ppt/media/image4.jpeg
   164476  1980-01-01 00:00   ppt/media/image5.jpeg
     6802  1980-01-01 00:00   ppt/media/image6.png
    19012  1980-01-01 00:00   ppt/media/image7.png
    32146  1980-01-01 00:00   ppt/media/image8.png
      ...
---------                     -------
   795623                     74 files
```

As you can see, my **sample.pptx** file contains some images in JPEG and PNG format.
Maybe your sample file contains some slides with images in a vector format (WMF or EMF); it's unclear to me (since I didn't find any reference in [the docs](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/phppowerpoint/latest/phppowerpoint.pdf)) if those formats are supported or not.
Eventually you should try with other PPTX files, just to make sure that the problem is not related to a specific one (you can find some under "[test/resources/files](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation/tree/develop/tests/resources/files)").
I've searched for a list of the supported image formats for PowerPoint files, but I haven't been able to find a precise response.
The only relevant links that I've found are the following:

- [ECMA 376 Open Office XML 1st Edition - Image Part](https://c-rex.net/projects/samples/ooxml/e1/Part1/OOXML_P1_Fundamentals_Image_topic_ID0EGXDO.html#topic_ID0EGXDO)
- [Office Implementation Information for ISO/IEC 29500
  Standards Support](https://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/MS-OI29500/[MS-OI29500].pdf) (2.1.32 Part 1 Section 15.2.14, Image Part, pages 57/58)
- [Images in Open XML documents](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dmahugh/2006/12/10/images-in-open-xml-documents/) (read the comments at the end of the page)
- [Question on OpenXML Developer Forum](http://openxmldeveloper.org/discussions/formats/f/15/p/418/944.aspx#944)

This means that also the presence in the PPTX file of an image in the TIFF or PICT (QuickDraw) format could lead to the error under consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Save your pptx again in PPT 2007 format in open office or MS Powerpoint.Its format issue.You are opening a very recent PPT format with 2007