# Style & layout is not copied while creating new pptx from pptx in PHPPresentation

Tags: php, powerpoint, phpoffice, phppresentation

I want to split slides of one pptx file into seperated pptx files, containing one slide each. The content/text is copied but the layout & styling is not copied. Here is the code.

Can anyone please help ?

```
<?php 

use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\PhpPresentation;
use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\IOFactory; 
use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Color;
use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Alignment;
use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Slide\SlideLayout;

 $objReader = \PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\IOFactory::createReader('PowerPoint2007');
 $objPHPPowerPoint = $objReader->load('a.pptx');

 $totalSlides = $objPHPPowerPoint->getSlideCount();
 $oMasterSlide = $objPHPPowerPoint->getAllMasterSlides()[0];

 $documentProperties =  $objPHPPowerPoint->getDocumentProperties();

 for ( $count = 0; $count < $totalSlides; $count++ ) {

     $objPHPPresentation = new PhpPresentation();
     $slide = $objPHPPowerPoint->getSlide(  $count );
     $background = $slide->getBackground();

     $newSlide = $objPHPPresentation->addSlide( $slide );
     $newSlide->setBackground ( $background );

     $objPHPPresentation->setAllMasterSlides(  $oMasterSlide );
     $objPHPPresentation->removeSlideByIndex(0);

     $oWriterPPTX = \PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPPresentation, 'PowerPoint2007');
     $oWriterPPTX->save($count.'.pptx');

}
```

Comment: if this works anything like phpOffice\phpspreadsheet then its likely you need to explicitly copy styles from the original and apply it to the new slide, there are all sorts of styles that could be in effect. If you can output the content and style of the original sheet then start cross checking the docs with the right functions to copy things that may be a start.

Comment: It's far simpler and more reliable (though possibly a bit slower) to ... For each slide in the current presentation, do a Save Copy As, then open the copy and working backwards, delete each slide EXCEPT the one you want to keep. Save. Repeat for each slide in the original presentation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's an issue with your code - more an issue with the underlying libraries - as mentioned here: [PhpPresentation imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format - PHP7.2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51634838/1196369)

It ran a test to see if it was something I could replicate - and I was able to. The key difference in my test was in one presentation I had a simple background, and in the other it was a gradient.

This slide caused problems:
[image: this caused problems]

But this one was copied over fine:
[image: this worked fine]

With the more complex background I got errors like:

> PHP Warning:  imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format

My code is even less complicated than yours, I just clone the original slideshow and remove all except a single slide before saving it:

```
for ( $count = 0; $count < $totalSlides; $count++ ) {
    $copyVersion = clone $objPHPPowerPoint;
    foreach ($copyVersion->getAllSlides() as $index => $slide) {
        if ($index !== $count) {
            $copyVersion->removeSlideByIndex($index);
        }
    }

    $oWriterPPTX = \PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\IOFactory::createWriter($copyVersion, 'PowerPoint2007');
    $oWriterPPTX->save($count.'.pptx');
}
```

Sorry if this doesn't exactly solve your problem, but hopefully it can help identify why it's happening. The other answer I linked to has more information about finding unsupported images types in your slides.

Comment: so If I downgrade php version to 7.1, then it will work ?

Comment: I don't think it's anything to do with PHP version, just some of the libraries not being very good at handling complex slide graphics. I could be wrong of course, maybe it's something that was recently introduced into PHPPresentation. However there are a few cases where people have had similar issues where style was lost: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation/issues/594 https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation/issues/542 https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation/issues/346 https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation/issues/291

Comment: in my case, even simple slides  are not copied at all. thats why I am worried here . Here is sample pptx file 
https://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/1452/0004185820.jpg

here is what I got after copy 
https://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/1452/6495259587.jpg

Comment: Can you try with just the basic copy like `$copyVersion = clone $objPHPPowerPoint;
    $oWriterPPTX = \PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\IOFactory::createWriter($copyVersion, 'PowerPoint2007');
    $oWriterPPTX->save($count.'.pptx');`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Aspose.Slides Cloud SDK for PHP](https://products.aspose.cloud/slides/php/) to split a presentation into separate slides and save them to many formats. You can evaluate this REST-based API making 150 free API calls per month for API learning and presentation processing. The following code example shows you how to split a presentation and save slides to PPTX format using Aspose.Slides Cloud:

```php
use Aspose\Slides\Cloud\Sdk\Api\Configuration;
use Aspose\Slides\Cloud\Sdk\Api\SlidesApi;
use Aspose\Slides\Cloud\Sdk\Model;

$configuration = new Configuration();
$configuration->setAppSid("my_client_id");
$configuration->setAppKey("my_client_key");

$slidesApi = new SlidesApi(null, $configuration);

$filePath = "example.pptx";

// Upload the file to the default storage.
$fileStream = fopen($filePath, 'r');
$slidesApi->uploadFile($filePath, $fileStream);

// Split the file and save the slides in PPTX format in the same folder.
$response = $slidesApi->split($filePath, null, Model\SlideExportFormat::PPTX);

// Download files of the slides.
foreach($response->getSlides() as $slide) {
    $slideFilePath = pathinfo($slide->getHref())["basename"];
    $slideFile = $slidesApi->downloadFile($slideFilePath);

    echo $slideFile->getRealPath(), "\r\n";
}
```

Sometimes it is necessary to split a presentation without using any code. In this case, you can use [Online PowerPoint Splitter](https://products.aspose.app/slides/splitter).

I work as a Support Developer at Aspose.